# Why is it quicker to use a temporary table when inserting data from a user function into a table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an inline table-valued function. I want to insert the output of that function into a table variable so I can pass it to another function.

```
DECLARE @PeopleToEmail mb.PeopleToEmailOrPhone;

INSERT INTO
    @PeopleToEmail
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mb.GetOptedInEmails('All')
;
```

On my dataset, this query takes 28 seconds to run.

However, if I use an intermediary temporary table, runtime drops to around 9 seconds.

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    #OptIns
FROM
    mb.GetOptedInEmails('All')
;

DECLARE @PeopleToEmail mb.PeopleToEmailOrPhone;

INSERT INTO
    @PeopleToEmail
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #OptIns
```

This makes no sense to me and means my code is twice as long as it needs to be. Can anyone help me

1. Understand why this is happening.
2. Think of another way of optimising the query without the intermediary table.

I'm stuck on SQL Server 2012. The function is quite long but you can [view it here](https://gist.github.com/mark-barnes-sp/253862ebf8440762aee51da3b0732178).

#### [No Temp Table](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyw8X_kQd)

[image: No Temp Table]

#### [Temp Table](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJcMGOJXu)

[image: Temp Table]

Comment: Can you share execution plans?

Comment: @Serg I've added execution plans. For the temp table, there should be two plans, but the second query plan is so simple I didn't both uploading it.

Comment: The way of optimizing this is to not use table variables or temp tables at all. Use inline Table Valued Functions, they are much faster. Without seeing the function code, cannot help. Please share the execution plans via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Essential difference I see is using parallelism when executing the `mb.GetOptedInEmails` on "Temp Table' case. According to this post [Inserts and other modifications to table variables can’t be parallelized.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/06/how-table-variables-mess-with-parallelism/)

Comment: @Charlieface I've added links to my plans at Brent Ozar's site. I'm not sure what you mean when you say I shouldn't use table variables and I should use inline table-valued functions instead. GetOptedInEmails() is an inline table-valued function, and I need the table variable because I need to pass the output from this function to another function. AFAIK, other ways of passing tables to functions are even more painful than using a temp table.

Comment: Ah ok didn't realize that. Yeah it's probably parallelism. But you should [edit] and add the code for the function. From the execution plan, it looks like the indexing isn't great, and at a guess: you've joined a bunch of tables in a CTE and self joined it a few times, also looks like it might have a `union` somewhere (instead of `union all`). Also seems to have a `TOP 100 PERCENT` in it?? Usually the best way to pass a table to another function is to rewrite it to take a single value, then `cross apply` it to every row of your table (but this can depend on what that other function is doing)

Comment: @Charlieface - the function is quite complex, but I've added it to the question. It gets email address from two separate databases, then merges them together. I don't have write access to the tables where the indexing isn't great. My function also uses `ROW_NUMBER()` which probably doesn't help. I use `UNION`, but if it would speed things up, I could use `UNION ALL` because the data should already be de-duped. I'm not sure how I could rewrite it using `CROSS APPLY`. Outside the function, performance is excellent. Perhaps I should give up on the function and use session variables and a view.

Comment: Indeed it is pretty complex. As I guessed: use `UNION ALL` it will be faster. I suggest you attempt to combine the two CTEs into one, as you currently have an anti-join on `AcousticWithDupes` inside `REWithDupes`, some choice `left join`s with filters based on previous joins would probably work. Look at the curretn indexing and see if you can somehow leverage your query to use it better. Regards `CROSS APPLY` I mean that if you want to use this result in a function, instead of passing a whole table, pass just the row values and `CROSS APPLY` this second function (which you haven't told us)